# Upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 over https

Tags: apt, upgrade

My ISP is using some kind of stupid transparent proxy and I am getting hash mismatch error during upgrade. This has happened before - but the ISP is either incompetent or uncooperative. Good thing they can cache https traffic. So I was wondering what I can do upgrade os over https with a peace of mind. Some repos are on https as mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/3q53kc/list_of_ubuntu_repository_mirrors_available_over/).

Or if there is anything else I can do. Moving the server or getting connecting from another server is a time consuming and service disrupting process and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Screenshot of hash mismatch error:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Imho a hosting provider with a broken HTTP proxy between my server and the general internet is a very good reason to switch the provider. Somehow I can hardly believe that you're the only customer running a Debian-based operating system with them. Everybody else would run into the same issues all the time.

Comment: @DavidFoerster At this moment it's not possible - but in the future, I will keep in mind. Its mistake - have a long day and didn't think it through.

Answer (score -1):

to switch to https from http you just need to update the urls in your source.list and source.list.d files to use https not http.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. `wget -t 1 -O /dev/null https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` and I get `Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|2001:67c:1560:8001::14|:443... failed: Connection refused.` Maybe some mirrors happen to accept HTTPS connections but definitely not the main archive.